# Proof that $f(A):=\sum_if(\lambda_i)e_i\otimes e^i$ is independent of the basis

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in L(V,V)$ be a diagonalizable operator on a finite-dim. $F$-vector space. Given a function $f$ defined on the set of all eigenvalues and with values in $F$, we defined $f(A)$ as follows in my class: We pick an eigenbasis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ and set$$f(A):=\sum_if(\lambda_i)e_i\otimes e^i.$$

Why is $f(A)$ independent of the chosen basis?

Comment: @BrianMoehring The $D$ in your first comment satisfies $\forall i:D_{ii}=\lambda_i$, whereas the $D$ in my question satisfies $\forall i:D_{ii}=f(\lambda_i)$, right? So I think that I disagree.

Comment: Are you sure this is true ? What if I take the basis $e_1,...,e_n$ and the basis $2e_1,2e_2,...,2e_n$. Then the values of $f(A)$ in each basis would be different by a factor of $4$.

Comment: @Digitallis Note that $e_i$ and $e^i$ transform differently. And yes, the formula in the title is used in QM.

Comment: @Digitallis To be more clear, if the basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ has dual basis $e^1, \ldots, e^n$, then the basis $2e_1, \ldots, 2e_n$ has dual basis $\frac12 e^1, \ldots, \frac12 e^n$ (note $(\frac12e^i)(2e_j) = e^ie_j = \delta_{i,j}$).  Since $(2e_i) \otimes (\frac12 e^i) = e_i \otimes e^i$, it's still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaking "Does the definition of the linear operator $f(A)$ depend on the eigenbasis?" with "Does $f(A)$ only have one matrix with respect to an eigenbasis?".  The former is the one in your question, and is true.  The latter is the one you are investigating in your attempt, and is false whenever $A$ isn't just multiplication by a scalar.

---

Let $E(A)$ denote the set of eigenvalues of $A$ and let $J(\lambda) = \{i \mid e_i \in \ker(A-\lambda I)\}$ denote the index set of the $i$ corresponding to each $\lambda \in E(A)$.

Let $v \in V$.  Since $A$ is diagonalizable, there are unique $v_t \in \ker(A - t I)$ for each $t \in E(A)$ such that $v = \sum_{t \in E(A)} v_t$.  Then,

$$\begin{align*}\left(\sum_i f(\lambda_i) e_i\otimes e^i\right)v &= \sum_{\lambda \in E(A)}f(\lambda)\sum_{i\in J(\lambda)} \sum_{t\in E(A)}((e_i\otimes e^i)v_t) \\ &= \sum_{\lambda \in E(A)} f(\lambda) \sum_{i\in J(\lambda)}(e_i\otimes e^i)v_\lambda \\ &= \sum_{\lambda\in E(A)}f(\lambda)v_\lambda\end{align*}$$

Comment: Ah so the point is that$$f(A)=\sum_\lambda f(\lambda)P_\lambda$$where $P_\lambda$ is the projector onto the $\lambda$-eigenspace. Thanks!