# Why does $B=M A M^{-1}$ with $A$ and $B$ diagonal imply that $f(B)=Mf(A) M^{-1} $?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be diagonal matrices such that $B=M A M{}^{-1}$. Why does this imply that $f(B)=M f(A) M^{-1}$, where for any diagonal matrix $D$ we define $f(D)$ by $f(D)_{ii}=f(D_{ii})$? Clearly this is true if $f$ is a polynomial...

Comment: If $f$ is analytic, then it holds for the same reason as for polynomials. Not sure what conditions you're putting on $f$ though, but you need it to be well defined when evaluating it at a matrix

Comment: @Lorago I am surprised. I thought that this is equivalent to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4710914/572841) where $f$ and even the field are arbitrary...but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: "Not sure what conditions you're putting on $f$ though, but you need it to be well defined when evaluating it at a matrix" - Actually my lecturer used the result in the title to define $f(A)$ for diagonalizable vector space endomorphisms $A$.

Comment: My comment was by no means intended as a full answer :)

Comment: @Lorago Your comment is very helpful though! You are probably right that more assumptions are needed. I hope that an answer will provide more clarity.

Comment: This is basically the continuous functional calculus if you want to look that up.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $L : V \to V$ is a linear transformation with associated matrices $D$ and $\tilde D$ in the basis $E = e_1,...,e_n$ and $\tilde E =\tilde e_1,...,\tilde e_n$. Also assume that $D$ is diagonal and that its eigenvalues are $D_{ii}$ like so,
$$ Le_i = D_{ii} e_i.$$ The fact that $D$ and $\tilde D = M^{-1}DM$ are both diagonal means that the bases $E,\tilde E$ are both eigenbases. That is, the matrices $D$ and $\tilde D$ are both diagonal.

To be more specific, recall that $\tilde e_i \in E$ is an eigenvector for $L$. In particular $L\tilde e_i = D_{kk}e_i$ for some eigenvalue $D_{kk}$ of $L$. Note that $k$ here depends on $i$ so we can emphasize this dependence by writing $k = \sigma(i)$. With this notation we have

$$ \tilde D_{ii} = D_{\sigma(i)\sigma(i)}$$

We now introduce the linear map
$$ f(L) : V \to V : e_i \mapsto f(D_{ii}) e_i$$
whose matrix $f(D)$ in the basis $E$ is diagonal with the diagonal elements $f(D_{ii})$

Clearly $e_i$ are still eigenvectors for $f(L)$. We now want to prove that the matrix of $f(L)$ in the basis $\tilde E$ is also diagonal.

Recall that $\tilde e_i \in E$ is an eigenvector for $L$. In particular $L\tilde e_i = D_{kk}e_i$ for some eigenvalue $D_{kk}$ of $L$ (This is the same $k = \sigma(i)$ defined above). Since we have a basis of eigenvectors $e_1,...,e_n$ it follows that $\tilde e_i$ is a linear combination of eigenvectors $e_{s_1},...,e_{s_{l_i}}$ with eigenvalue $D_{kk}$.

Hence applying $f(L)$ to $\tilde e_i = \sum_{l = 1}^{l_i} \lambda_l^i e_{s_l}$ we obtain
$$
\begin{align*}
f(L) \tilde e_i &= f(L)\sum_{l = 1}^{l_i} \lambda_l^i e_{s_l} \\ 
&=\sum_{l = 1}^{l_i} \lambda_l^i f(L)e_{s_l} \\
&= \sum_{l = 1}^{l_i} \lambda_l^i f(D_{kk})e_{s_l} \\
&= f(D_{kk}) \tilde{e_i}.
\end{align*}
$$

This proves that $M^{-1}f(D)M$ is diagonal and such that
$$ (M^{-1}f(D)M)_{ii} = f(D_{kk}) = f(D_{\sigma(i)\sigma(i))}) = f(\tilde D_{ii}) = f(\tilde D)_{ii}$$
which ends the proof.

There are therefore no extra assumptions needed on $f$.

Comment: Sorry, but aren't you answering a different question now? My question only involves matrices. What would be the $L$ in my question?

Comment: Inititially I thought that we can consider the case $V=\displaystyle F^n$ and let $L\in L(\displaystyle F^n,F^n)$ be the function induced by $D\in \displaystyle F^{n\times n}$ (in other words, we take $E$ to be the standard basis) - but then the assumption that the $\tilde e_i$ are eigenvectors of $L$ is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: @Filippo Exactly take $V = F^n$ and $L$ the function induced by $D$.  Also take $E$ the standard basis now take $\tilde E$ the be the column vectors of the matrix $M$. Then $M^{-1}DM$ is the matrix of $L$ in the basis $\tilde E$. Since $M^{-1}DM$ is diagonal by the hypothesis this means that $\tilde e_i$ are eigenvectors of $L$

Answer (score 2):

I think the question uses a function $f$ which is defined on the field $\mathsf k$ where the matrices $D,M$ *etc.* are elements of $\mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathsf k)$. If that is the case, then the definition of $f(A)$ for $A$ diagonalisable can be given invariantly as follows:

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, it induces a linear map $\alpha_A\colon \mathsf k^n \to \mathsf k^n$ (viewing $\mathsf k^n$ as $n\times 1$ matrices, or column vectors) given by $\alpha_A(v)= Av$. Write $E_\lambda = \{v \in \mathsf k^n: \alpha_A(v)=\lambda.v\}$ for the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $\alpha_A$, so that the eigenvalues of $A$ are precisely $\sigma(A)=\{\lambda \in \mathsf k: E_{\lambda} \neq \{0\}\}$

Let $\mathrm{Mat}^{ss}_n(\mathsf k)$ denote the set of diagonalizable $n\times n$ matrices, that is, the matrices $A$ for which there is a basis of $\mathsf k^n$ consisting of eigenvectors for $\alpha_A$. Then $A \in \mathrm{Mat}_n^{ss}(\mathsf k)$ if and only if
$$
\label{direct sum}
\tag{$\dagger$}
V = \bigoplus_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} E_{\lambda}.
$$

Now assuming $A$ is diagonalisable, if we write $\pi_\lambda \colon V\to E_{\lambda}$ for each $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$, so that if $v \in V$, $v= \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} \pi_{\lambda}(v)$, then we have $\alpha_A = \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)}\lambda.\pi_{\lambda}$. Hence if $f\colon \mathsf k \to \mathsf k$ is any function from $\mathsf k$ to itself, we may define $f(\alpha_A)$ to be the linear map  $\sum_{\lambda\in \sigma(A)} f(\lambda).\pi_{\lambda}$, and then $f(A)$ the matrix associated to that linear map (i.e. the matrix with columns $f(\alpha_A)(e_i)$ where $\{e_i\}_{1\leq i\leq n}$ is the standard basis of the space of column vectors). If you pick a basis of eigenvectors of $\alpha_A$ in order to obtain a diagonal matrix, then it is easy to see that the matrix of $f(\alpha_A)$ with respect to that basis will be diagonal with entries $f(\lambda)$ for a basis vector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, our definition coincides with the one given in the question, and since it does not use a choice of basis, it shows that the definition in the question is in fact independent of that choice also.

Thus starting from the formula $f(\alpha_A) = \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)}f(\lambda)\pi_{\lambda}$ we see that whenever we have a basis of $\mathsf k^n$ such that the matrix of $\alpha_A$ is diagonal with respect to it, then so is the matrix of $f(\alpha_A)$, with diagonal entries given by the images of the diagonal entries of $A$ under the function $f$. This immediately implies your question, because $MDM^{-1} = \tilde{D}$ implies that $M$ is the change of basis matrix between two bases with respect to which $\alpha_A$ is given by a diagonal matrix.

This method of extending functions of the base field to diagonalisable linear maps works in infinite-dimensional settings also, (where it sometimes gets referred to as "functional calculus") though for it to be of significance, one needs to know there is a reasonably large/interesting class of linear operators which are diagonalisable. Perhaps the most natural context where that is indeed the case is where $V$ is a Hilbert space, that is a (complete) infinite-dimensional inner product space, so that any $\alpha\colon V\to V$ has an "adjoint" $\alpha^*\colon V\to V$ satisfying $\langle \alpha(v_1),v_2)\rangle = \langle v_1,\alpha^*(v_2)\rangle$ for all $v_1,v_2 \in V$. Then the space of self-adjoint operators $\mathcal S(V)=\{\alpha \in \mathrm{Hom}(V,V):\alpha = \alpha^*\}$ (where $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$ means the space of bounded linear maps) is a natural space of linear operators which are all diagonalisable.

[If (\eqref{direct sum}) is not familiar, to see that it is equivalent to $\mathsf k^n$ having a basis of eigenvectors for $\alpha_A$, suppose first that the direct sum decomposition (\eqref{direct sum}) holds. If we pick a basis $B_{\lambda}$ of $E_{\lambda}$ for each $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$, then $B = \bigcup_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} B_{\lambda}$ is a basis of $\mathsf k^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $\alpha_A$. Conversely, if $B$ is a basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $\alpha_A$, then each $b \in B$ lies in some $E_{\lambda}$ and hence in $\bigoplus_{\lambda\in \sigma(A)}E_{\lambda}$, but since $V = \mathrm{span}_{\mathsf k}(B)$, it follows $V\subseteq \bigoplus_{\lambda\in \sigma(A)} E_{\lambda}$. Since the reverse containment holds trivially, it follows $V = \bigoplus_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)} E_{\lambda}$ as required.]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am familiar with the formula $$f(A)=\sum_\lambda f(\lambda)\pi_\lambda$$for diagonalizable endomorphisms on a finite-dim. $k$-vector space, but how does this help to answer the question in the title?

Comment: I've modified my answer so that hopefully it is now clear why the invariant description of $f(A)$ implies an explanation for the question you posed. If it isn't, let me know!

Comment: Thank you for your efforts (+1)! My head is very foggy at the moment, I will properly read your answer later on.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Digitallis' answer:

Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be the standard basis of $F^n$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ the basis defined by $\forall i:Mv_i=e_i$

Firstly, note that $MAM{}^{-1}e_i=B_{ii}e_i$ is equivalent to $Av_i=B_{ii}v_i$ and hence
$$\forall i:v_i=\sum_{\alpha:A_{\alpha\alpha}=B_{ii}}e^\alpha v_ie_\alpha$$
which implies that $Mf(A)M^{-1}=f(B)$:
\begin{align}
\forall i:Mf(A)M^{-1}e_i=Mf(A)v_i=Mf(A)\sum_{\alpha:A_{\alpha\alpha}=B_{ii}}e^\alpha v_ie_\alpha=M\sum_{\alpha:A_{\alpha\alpha}=B_{ii}} e^\alpha v_i f(A)e_\alpha\\=M\sum_{\alpha:A_{\alpha\alpha}=B_{ii}} e^\alpha v_i f(A_{\alpha\alpha})e_\alpha=f(B_{ii})M\sum_{\alpha:A_{\alpha\alpha}=B_{ii}} e^\alpha v_i e_\alpha=f(B_{ii})Mv_i=f(B_{ii})e_i=f(B)e_i
\end{align}